# Get local DateTime in Denmark from server in Ireland

Tags: c#, azure, datetime

I have a solution in Azure in Ireland. I live in Denmark.

Would it be correct, to save all my times and dates as `universal = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()` in my database in Ireland?

When I need the danish time, I cannot: `universal.ToLocalTime()` because I’m still on the server in Ireland. Instead I could write:

```
danish = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(universal, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time"));
```

But I think it’s a long way.

Alternative 1: I convert date to danish, before I save in my database in Ireland.
Alternative 2: There are one timezone between Denmark and Ireland, so I could: `danish = dateTime.AddHours(1)`, but perhaps it could give errors with the summer and winther time.

Comment: We don't usually *fix* working code.

Comment: your first implementation is the best.  If you are displaying the time anywhere don't forget to specify the culture info.

Comment: Why convert the time on the server at all? Keep it in UTC and let the client decide which time zone is applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

- There's nothing *wrong* with writing `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`, but understand that under the hood that is fetching the current UTC time, converting to local time, then converting back to UTC.  Thus, it's both shorter and more efficient to simply call `DateTime.UtcNow` to get the UTC time directly without conversions.
- The server on which your code is running is irrelevant (or should be).  Additionally, all Azure instances have their local time zone set to UTC anyway, so you will not see any effects from Ireland's local time zone.
- Yes, `"Romance Standard Time"` is the correct Windows identifier for the local time in Denmark.  If you are running on a non-Windows platform, you should use `"Europe/Copenhagen"` instead.  If you are writing for multi-platform usage, then use `"Europe/Copenhagen"` with my [TimeZoneConverter library](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter).
- If you just wanted to write *shorter* code, you might be able to do the following:

  ```
    DateTime danish = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(universal, "Romance Standard Time");
  ```

  I say *might*, because this will only be correct if the `DateTime` you've got in your `universal` variable has its `Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  If you've set that previously using `DateTime.SpecifyKind`, then this will work.  On the other hand, if you have just retrieved this value from a database, then by default the `Kind` will by `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  The key difference being that `ConvertTimeFromUtc` treats `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` as if it were `DateTimeKind.Utc`, while `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` treats `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` as if it were `DateTimeKind.Local`.

  In other words, if you don't set the `Kind` explicitly, it would convert from *local* time to Danish time.  *However*, since Azure runs its local time zone as UTC, you'd get the same result.  Just you might get different results when running elsewhere.
- You might consider using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.  This usually results in clearer code and less errors.  (`DateTimeKind` is not used with `DateTimeOffset`.)  Of course it depends on what exactly you're using this data for, but often it's a good idea.

About your proposed alternatives, I suggest neither.  Your original code is better.  My thoughts on each:

> Alternative 1: I convert date to danish, before I save in my database in Ireland.

It depends on what you're representing.

- If this is a unique point in time (the time something *happened*, usually in the past) - then you should keep it as UTC.  That allows conversion to any time zone correctly.
- On the other hand, if you are representing the time something is *scheduled* to happen (in the future), then most often it's the local time that matters most.  This is especially important for recurring events in time zones with DST, or events in time zones that might be volatile (where the government makes frequent short-notice changes).

> Alternative 2: There are one timezone between Denmark and Ireland, so I could: `danish = dateTime.AddHours(1)`, but perhaps it could give errors with the summer and winter time.

You should not add or subtract time to adjust time zones.  After all - you're not talking about a different point in time an hour in the future or an hour in the past.

Also, Denmark and Ireland may be similar today, but that doesn't mean they have *always* been that way, and it doesn't mean they will necessarily stay that way in the future.  Ireland has a different time zone identifiers (`"GMT Standard Time"` on Windows, `"Europe/Dublin"` on other platforms).

Answer (score 2):

Use server Utc time to save record in `database` in order to avoid any time differences when converting datetime `from` and then converting it `back`. Once the record use `Utc` datetime then you can easily convert it to any time zone, so for example: system requires to convert datetime to Denmark local time, and in future it might need to show in Germany datetime

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time");
DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
```